# Add shared OneDrive document to my drive

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive

This seems like something that should be very simple, but I can't figure it out. A colleague has shared a OneDrive document with me. When I click the email, the document opens in Word Online. I can open the document and edit in Word with no problem. The issue is that I don't want to have to dig up this link every time I need to edit the document.

I can open the "Shared" section of OneDrive at onedrive.live.com, but I would like to move this file into my own list of files. Is this possible?

To clarify: I am collaborating on this document using OneDrive. I want to be able to place the file someone else has shared with me in a folder in my OneDrive so that I can keep my files organized. I do not want an unshared copy of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for a feature that is still under development, targeted to be released in stages.

See https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/6325866-allow-folders-to-be-shared-co-owned-with-access-sy

> How does it work? We have a new action on OneDrive, called “Add to my OneDrive.” Whenever you are using OneDrive on the web, or through the mobile app, you’ll see this when you are browsing content that others have shared with you. Clicking “Add to my OneDrive” will add that folder to your OneDrive. From then on, whenever you browse your OneDrive, you’ll be able to see any of the shared folders you’ve added. And on the sync client, when you select what folders to sync, you’ll see all the shared folders you’ve added. Select the shared folder(s) you want and they’ll immediately begin syncing to your PC or Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, if you only have access to that single file and not the containing folder, the easiest way is to open the file in Word and `Save As...`

Comment: Maybe I needed to be more clear. I am collaborating on this document with several others, and would like to work on this version by accessing through my OneDrive.

Comment: I'm confused I'm afraid. The doc belongs to someone who has shared it, you want to further collaborate? So get the originator to share to the others. If you want a COPY to collaborate with others, make the copy as I've said - save it to your OneDrive and reshare.

Comment: Added some clarification to the question above.

Comment: As stated, open the original in the Word application and Save As... choose your OneDrive as the location (if you have the OneDrive application installed). If you don't have the application, save to your Documents folder and then upload to your OneDrive via the web interface. Then share with other people.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to save an Internet shortcut. When you are editing the document in Word Online, save it as a favorite (using Internet Explorer terms). Then drag that favorite to your Desktop. Now, move the shortcut to wherever you want. Whenever you want to edit the Word document online, you just double-click on the shortcut to take you to that document.

Comment: What I want is to do the same thing in OneDrive that I've been doing for years in Dropbox. When someone shares a file with me, I can add it to my own Dropbox and access the shared file that way, rather than having to click a link in my web browser every time I want to open the file.

Comment: I created my answer since you said you retrieve the file via web (onedrive.live.com). If you are have OneDrive desktop client installed, you can create a "junction" from the file on your OneDrive folder to put it somewhere else on your hard drive. Your question is somewhat unclear on your process... whether you want to edit online, or edit with a local copy that is syncing (such as DropBox).